# Why is it not advised to unzip flutter in program files?

Tags: flutter, command-prompt, unzip, program-files

When I unzip flutter in program files, flutter doctor command hangs when tried to execute from the command line even after adding its path. The problem gets fixed when I unzip flutter in some other directory. I wanted to know the reason for this??

Comment: `%PROGRAMFILES%` typically needs administrator privileges to write to, and the Flutter tools will want to create cache directories, download files, and update itself.  I suspect it might work if you change the ACLs of the directory that you extracted Flutter to in `%PROGRAMFILES%`, but you're better off extracting it to a user-owned folder.